# Is it possible to install the .ipa with distribution profile

Tags: ios, app-store

I have generated .ipa file with distribution profile created from the client's developer account. when i try to instal the .ipa file in device.I am getting no valid provisioning profile.Is it possible to install the .ipa with distribution profile?

Comment: How are you installing the `.ipa`?

Answer (score 0):

Create **ADHOC** **distribution profile** by selecting the devices you want to install in. See image below

[image]

Comment: Please provide more context to that image; what app/website is it?

Comment: You can also create Provisioning Profiles in Xcode too, right?

Comment: yes you can also create a provisioning profile with UDID of the devices added to them on which you would want the ipa to be installed. though the number of devices are limited.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Will it work, if we choose distribution method as appstore?